# linq to sql insert on multiple table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to insert a record on two tables using "linq to sql" 
I write this code:

```
dataclass temp1=new dataclass(connectionstring);
dataclass temp2=new dataclass(connectionstring);
human t=new human();
t.name=textbox.text;
temp1.insertonsubmit(t);
temp1.submitchange();

int x=t.id;

car y=new car();
y.name=textbox2.text;
temp2.insertonsubmit(y);
temp2.submitchange();
```

But I have a error in this line:

```
temp2.insertonsubmit(y);
```

The Error :

> string or binary data would be truncated.the statement has been
>   terminated

Why do this happen? How can I solve do this?

Comment: Could you tell us the error you are having? Its hard to tell now what is going wrong with the limited information you provide.

Comment: Why do you have two `dataclass` instances? Can you not use `temp1` for both inserts and call `SubmitChanges()` once?

Comment: @chead23 no , becaues i need the id from t to use on temp2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, this error "String or Binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated" will occur only if any mismatch between database column size and provided data length.

So can you check the column size of `y.name` in database. If it is less than your data length then increase it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are trying to insert data into a varchar/varbinary column that is smaller than the data you wish to insert.

My guess would be that `textbox2.text` contains more characters than `car.name` supports.